# Multi State button like toggle in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement a feature in table where user can set value of cell by clicking on it.
there can be say 3-4 states,also a ng-model attached to it.

*I looked for the toggle button in angularjs but they are mere on/off type.*

In short; Clicking on the button will set the value as: Active, Inactive, Excluded 
Looking for solution with multiple state.
Any help with this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the below working example :

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/ZavXw/9/

and controller code

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.btnarr=0;
    $scope.btnTxt=["Active","Inactive","Excluded"]
    $scope.change=function(){
        switch($scope.btnarr)
        {
            case 0:
                $scope.btnarr=1;
               break;
            case 1:
                 $scope.btnarr=2
               break;
            case 2:
                 $scope.btnarr=0;
               break;                
        }
    }
}
```

OR

Shorter Version of Controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.btnarr=0;
    $scope.btnTxt=["Active","Inactive","Excluded"]
    $scope.change=function(){
      $scope.btnarr = ($scope.btnarr + 1) % $scope.btnTxt.length;
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-modle="btnarr" ng-Click="change()">{{btnTxt[btnarr]}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much to it.

When I make menus in Angular, on each item, I'll have a "select" function, which then selects that particular object, out of the list...

Making an iterable button is even smoother:

```
var i = 0;
$scope.states[
    { text : "Active" },
    { text : "Inactive" },
    { text : "Excluded" }
];

$scope.currentState = $scope.states[i];

$scope.cycleState = function () {
    i = (i + 1) % $scope.states.length;
    $scope.currentState = $scope.states[i];
    // notify services here, et cetera
}


<button ng-click="cycleState">{{currentState.text}}</button>
```

The actual array of states wouldn't even need to be a part of the `$scope` here, if this was the only place you were using those objects -- the only object you'd need to have on the `$scope` would then be `currentState`, which you set when you call the `cycleState` method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle with two possibilities: selecting the state from a list or cycling by clicking the button itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/evzKV/4/

The JS code looks like this:

```
angular.module('test').directive('toggleValues',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>Set Status:<div ng-repeat="value in values" class="status" ng-click="changeTo($index)">{{value}}</div><span ng-click="next()">Current Status (click to cycle): {{values[selectedValue]}}</span></div>',
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.values = ["Active", "Inactive", "Pending"];
        $scope.changeTo = function (index) {
            $scope.selectedValue = (index < $scope.values.length) ? index : 0;
        };

        $scope.next = function () {
            $scope.selectedValue = ($scope.selectedValue + 1) % $scope.values.length;
            // the modulo is stolen from Norguard (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18592722/2452446) - brilliant idea
        };

        $scope.selectedValue = 0;
    }]
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <toggle-values></toggle-values>
</div>
```

Comment: Well shucks.  It's not really a new idea, but I'll take it.  The other really clean way to mod these types of things is in two statements: `i += 1; i %= length;` From a micro-op perspective there's no real difference.  But it can look really clean.