# Angular Three Way Button with Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for an answer to this question:

[Multi State button like toggle in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592331/multi-state-button-like-toggle-in-angularjs)

...but using a directive.  The main reason being that I'm trying to achieve isolate scope in order to create a reusable button.  I have tried:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('buttonToggle', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myBtnArr: "="
            },
            myBtnTxt: ["AND", "OR", "NOT"],
            template: '<button>{{ myBtnTxt[myBtnArr] }} </button>'
        }
    });
```

With something like this in the HTML:

```
<div button-toggle my-btn-arr=0></div>
```

But Angular doesn't seem to like any flavor of this, either showing the button but not the text or throwing the cryptic ***a.match is not a function*** error.  Thoughts?

Comment: you have `myBtnArr` attribute wrong way..it should be hyphen separated like `my-btn-arr="someVariable"` where as `someVariable` will be scope variable, which hold value of `0`

Comment: You are correct but that's because I incorrectly transcribed the html, edited.  Your solution seems to me like it would not create isolate scope?

Comment: If I do that then it's a string and not a number, which is what the "=" is meant to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your directive to include a link function.  Then place myBtnTxt on scope in there.  Like so:

```
app.directive('buttonToggle', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myBtnArr: "="
      },
    template: '<button>{{myBtnTxt[myBtnArr]}}</button>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.myBtnTxt = ["AND", "OR", "NOT"];
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yep!  Thanks jbrown!